# Retrieve Data from Database to Textbox using ADODB in C#

Tags: c#

I am using `ADODB` Connection in `C#`.

Following is from `VB` code I want it like in `C#`.

```
    empcode.Text = IIf(IsDBNull(mRS("Accode").Value), "", mRS("Accode").Value)
```

Like above code, I want to retrieve data to a textbox in `C#`.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really include more context to your question, but here goes:

```
empcode.Text = mRS.Fields["Accode"].Value == System.DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : mRS.Fields["Accode"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I had tried above code but it is giving error as "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type 'Recordsrt'".

Comment: And mRS is Recordset.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please update your question with your full code.

Comment: txtdef.Text = mRS.Fields["Ask1"].Value == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : mRS.Fields["Ask1"].Value.ToString();

Comment: That's exactly what my answer said (on a different field as per your question)